# Hexadecimal Counter

Tags: code-golf, hexadecimal

[image: Image of Hex Conversion Table w/ counter]

**Hexadecimal** is a base 16 counting system that goes from `0` to `f`. Your job is to make a counter that will display these numbers.

**Example:**

```
$ python counter.py
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 30
```

**Rules:**

- The numbers may be separated by spaces, tabs, or new lines.
- The minimum number you must go to is `30` (48 in decimal).

  - You may also make the program print numbers forever until it is stopped.
- Letters may be in uppercase or lowercase (`A` or `a`).
- No built in functions allowed (that directly affect hexadecimal conversions/counting).
- Leading zeros are allowed
- It may start from `1` or `0`
- Shortest code wins!

Comment: @Sp3000 How built in are they? Converting decimal to hex?

Comment: @Sp3000 No built in functions allowed!

Comment: @manatwork uppercase is fine

Comment: How about general base conversion functions then?

Comment: @Sp3000 Sure (ignore this, 15 character limit)

Comment: If the program prints things repeatedly, but breaks at some point beyond `30`, (say, at `FF`) is that okay?

Comment: @BrainSteel Yes, as long as it gets to `30`

Comment: A couple of questions I'd rather have answered now than later: 1. Can the count start from zero? 2. Are leading zeroes allowed?

Comment: @Dennis Yes and yes!

Comment: Is it OK if my solution prints an exta newline between 0F and 10, and 1F and 20, ...?

Comment: @Mauris yes . . .

Comment: Cool! What about tab-separated output?

Comment: @Mauris Yes! That sure is going to be interesting...

Comment: Can I use a format string that converts parameters to hex inside a string? It's not a function.

Comment: @mbomb007 Do you mean Regex? There's Retina for that.

Comment: No, a Python format string containing `%x`.

Comment: So if a language has a built-in that only converts to hex it isn't allowed, but a general one such as `5.base(16)` is allowed?

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills That isn't allowed either.

Comment: I was looking at the previous comments and it looked like you agreed to *general base conversion functions* when Sp3000 asked. Also does that include `printf` type functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth - 12 bytes

Uses cartesian product, and sorts at the end to get in correct order, then joins by spaces. Prints `00-ff` inclusive.

```
jdS^s+<G6UT2
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jdS%5Es%2B%3CG6UT2&debug=1).

```
jd             Join by spaces
 S             Sort lexiographically
  ^    2       Cartesian product repeat twice
   s+          Append then concatenate entire list
    <G6        First six of alphabet
    UT         Range 0-9
```

Answer (score 7):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 26

Counts from 0x0 to 0x3F:

```bash
echo {0..3}{{0..9},{A..F}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@h2kBPz7i2GkRZ1upUO@rpudXW/v8PAA)

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, <s>21</s> 14 bytes

```
A,_6,'Af++m*S*
```

Prints the numbers 00 to 9F.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=A%2C_6%2C%27Af%2B%2Bm*S*).

#### How it works

```
A,             e# Push [0 ... 9].
  _            e# Push a copy.
   6,          e# Push [0 ... 5].
     'Af+      e# Add 'A' to each. This pushes "ABCDEF".
         +     e# Concatenate. This pushes [0 ... 9 'A' ... 'F'].
          m*   e# Cartesian product. This pushes [[0 0] ... [9 'F'].
            S* e# Join, separating by spaces.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 52

```python
a=0
for b in'0123456789ABCDEF'*4:print`a`+b;a+=b>'E'
```

Prints `00` to `3F`. Takes advantage of the fact that the first digit `a` is always a number in this range. Loops through four cycles of the second digit `b`, incrementing `a` whenever the second digit is `F`.

This is one char shorter than the more direct

```python
for a in'0123':
 for b in'0123456789ABCDEF':print a+b
```

Comment: `n ='0123'` should save some chars

Comment: @Caridorc How exactly?

Comment: by writing `thing in n + restofstring`

Comment: @Caricord Not sure what you mean, it's longer to do `n='0123'
for a in n:
 for b in n+'456789ABCDEF':print a+b`

Comment: sorry I had to do some more precise counting :)

Comment: @Caridorc A metal shortcut I use is that saving to a variable costs 4 chars, so it needs >4 chars of saving to compensate, so saving 4 chars for `0123` for something else isn't enough.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

Same approach as the Python ones I suppose.

```js
for(i of c='0123456789ABCDEF')for(j of c)console.log(i+j)
```

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, 63 bytes

```
:For(I,0,4,16⁻¹
:Disp sub(" 0123456789ABCDEF",1+16fPart(I),2
:Output(7,1,int(I
:End
```

This is 63 bytes, according to the memory management screen on my calculator, a TI-84+. Make sure to start the program with a partially filled home screen!

Comment: Did you remember to subtract the length of the 9-byte header and the program name from the code length?

Answer (score 4):

### **Befunge-93, 57 bytes**

```
<_v#-*44:+1,*84,g2:\,g2:\
^ >$1+:9-!#@_0
0123456789ABCDEF
```

Prints numbers from `00`to `8F`. If you prefer your programs to run forever, the version below is non-terminating and will continually output all numbers from `00` to `FF`.

```
<_v#-*44:+1,*84,g2:\,g2:\
^ >$1+:35*`!*0
0123456789ABCDEF
```

Comment: You can save a couple bytes in -98 with <_v#-f:+1, ',g2:\,g2:\. Can't see many improvements beyond that.

Comment: `0123456789ABCDEF01g::88+/2-0g,88+%0g,9,1+01p`

Comment: That's 44 bytes. It loops forever, like your second solution, and prints wrong results past the second 1F. It requires an implementation (such as the reference implementation `bef.c`) that silently ignores unknown commands (`ABCDEF`).

Comment: (The OP mentions it's okay for a solution to "break" somewhere past hitting `30` -- this one will slowly overflow the stack, so I suppose there's some point of termination. Also, output is tab-separated; the OP said this was fine.) Oh, the Befunge implementation you use should also initialize the whole 80x25 torus with spaces (ASCII `0x20`).

Comment: @Mauris Regarding your comment about the implementation needing to instantiate the entire torus with spaces, would this affect the byte count for my code presented? I only counted the necessary characters rather than filling in the corners with spaces.

Comment: @Jacob In -98 doesn't the `f` command push 15? If so, the loop would break on 14, i.e. once it has printed `E`, though I suppose that could be fixed by changing the minus for a backtick...

Comment: @Sok Well, I was talking about my solution; I don't know if yours relies on that. [The reference implementation does this](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93/blob/master/src/bef.c#L258), so it should be pretty standard behavior. I don't think you should count the corners you didn't fill in!

Comment: @Sok you're right. I was thinking it pushed 16 for some reason...

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 22 bytes

```
1{_GbA,6,'af++f=oNo)}h
```

This runs forever, and thus is probably one of the rare times where it's a good idea *not* to include a permalink.

Comment: `oNo` is the same as `n` in TIO.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>78</s> 75 bytes

```c
x(y){return y+48+y/10*7;}f(j){for(j=0;printf("%c%c ",x(j/16),x(15&j++)););}
```

We define a function `f()` to be called with no arguments for printing, and a helper function `x(int)`. This breaks at `FF`.

Amazingly, this is one byte shorter than the more obvious:

```c
char*s="0123456789ABCDEF";h(j){for(j=0;printf("%c%c ",s[j/16],s[15&j++]););}
```

*Warning: it is not recommended to run this code outside of a debug environment...*

Testing:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```c
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 (...)
```

Of course, the more robust (and cheat-y) approach is this 34-byte function:

```c
g(i){for(i=0;printf("%x ",i++););}
```

Comment: Started trying this but my answer was too similar.  You can save several bytes by making the first %c into %d and omitting the function.  It's only valid up to 9F then though.

Comment: `return y+` could possibly be `y+=`.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

```
VJs++kUT<G6FYJ+NY
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VJs%2B%2BkUT%3CG6FYJ%2BNY&debug=0)

### How it works:

```
         <G6         # "abcdef"
       UT            # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
      k              # an empty string (so + means concatenation, not addition)
   s++               # join them all ("0123456789abcdef")
  J                  # call this J
 V                   # for each N in J...
            FYJ      # for each Y in J...
               +NY   # print N and Y
```

Comment: `jb^+jkUT<G6 2` uses the cartesian product to do the same thing, still seems golfable...

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, <strike>67</strike> 62 bytes

```
(x=''.replace.bind('0123456789ABCDEF',/./g))(n=>x(o=>' '+n+o))
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 22 bytes

```
>{;~'0123456789abcdef'
```

Counts to `ff`. Prints an extra newline between each block of `0x10` numbers, like so:

```
...
0d
0e
0f

10
11
...
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mumps - 65 bytes

```
S Q="0123456789ABCDEF" F I=1:1:16 F J=1:1:16 W $E(Q,I),$E(Q,J),!
```

Nope... Mumps ain't dead yet! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## TheC64Mini and Commodore BASIC (C64/128, PET, VIC-20, C16/+4) - 164 BASIC and Tokenized bytes used

```
 0 fOd=.to255:n=d:fOi=1to.stE-1:h%(i)=n/(16^i):n=n-(h%(i)*(16^i)):nEi:h$=""
 1 fOi=1to.stE-1:ifh%(i)<10tHh$=h$+cH(48+h%(i))
 2 ifh%(i)>9tHh$=h$+cH(55+h%(i))
 3 nEi:?h$"  ";:nEd
```

Prints a double-space after the hex number to nicely align the printing at 40/80 columns as well as the 22 columns on the VIC-20.

[image: Commodore Plus/4 Hex counter innit]

Answer (score 2):

## [Malbolge](https://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge.shtml), 900 bytes

To be improved...

```
D'``@"\7}|X9E1gwuR21=p(:9%IZYEg}eA/ya>O_)([Zvotm3qponmfN+Lbg`ed]\"CB^W\Uy<;WVONSLp3ONMLEDhH*)?>b%A@?87[;:9876/S3,P0/.-&J$)"'~D|{"y?}|utyr8potmrqpi/mfN+Lbg`e^$bDZ_^]VzZSXQVUTSLp3ONMLEDhH*)EDCB;@?8\6|:32V6v.32+O)o'&J*)i'&%|Bcb~w|u;yxwvutVrkj0nmfN+iKg`_%cE[`Y}@V[ZYXWPtT6LKJImM/KJIBAe(D=<A:98\[;{32V6v.-,P0).',%I)"!E%|#"y?w_{ts9Zvutsrkpi/mfNjihg`e^$b[Z~X]\[ZYRv98TSLKoO10FKDh+GFE>CB;_?>=}|49870/.R2+*Non&%I#"!&%${A!~}_u;yxqpo5mrqpoh.lkdibgf_%]\[!_XW{[ZYXQPt7SRQPOHGkKJIHAF?cC<;@?8\6;492V6v.-,P*p.'K+$j"'~D|#"y~wv<]yxqvutsrk1onmfN+cba`&d]#DZ_^]VzTSXQVOs65QJINGkE-IBAe(D=<A:98\654981Uv.32+*)M-,%k#(!E}$#"!x>v{t:xwputm3kpoh.fN+Lbg`ed]\"!Y^]VzZYXQVOsS54JImMFKJIHAe?>C<`@?87[;{32V05.-2+O)o-,+$H('&}Cdzy~wv<]sxqvonm3k1oQmf,jihgfeG]#a`_X|V[TxXQPUTMLp3ONMLEDhH*)ED=a;@?>76;4X816/43,P*).',%I#i!&}|Bcb~w|u;yxwputm3qSong-kjihgfH%]\a`_XW{UTYXQuUTMRKPOHlFKDhBAe?>=B;_9>=6Z:981Uv.32+*)M-,%k#(!E%$#c!x>|u;yxZpo5srqSi/z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJXd6JQFEZ/i1IUe8WOsWDvBRU1YEWCBuwawb/uHGBmVjJrXu7jXvvu7@xm27m8FVavV97G82/WSURThzHaL1zPnYA/pdjjMazMjmhBW2W89xnV5Aj7mL3Ip11wr8ifu3XDWZsL/Go5nVhz2ffBpH9PJgZMs9GtKcFmo16j85uSg0hTcyzzlo5Gxol4LBohvd2gq@Xzetx4BSWstmdefVjvaU09n@6HqAL0w14RvX/p7@g8z3LvU@aL7Q7bTL/3k07nc9kE0CekGg8GGPLiCQacTUK24RUHIdpwTM0u5s@rek7cb9fL@cQcpA@f4S5WBZ7DFvSYH2lvzJgdDQetU4@sVSvlXd0LbzazsudTyQxYT8aJh0l3gzvhsbmwMmG10JiKgPuVe5yOMRbox4Nkun@IG9N9zD6H0wnQO5dYFNyrctPvK1TzG2exQFPgzqWplKaGoAw06QScjob8iWNlxGrBMfSRsTw1TneH4mG9jLzxbKWlOBfWHAZcCzccPHT3dusU6XbarWapKIF7KVNIL3JJs0wiFPvj7lA8tqoT/TC6g/vzeklOgW66@81VF/MZjy@nyO/uPb1780iG25VyoyjR7h9lyDC4@/tGdwdRd7swCbFbaA2FH9yoy@MUv12VM9yMpLt/vxnLyFh1ZNC74ZDevWC4r9JULsmbN6N394U9bmNVt8uJluw2XMstv0z3I7iDdRDc27u1S@@@XhWnyIznhioz7t2gTL9X/@dmUjMoQ0WgzDDqJ70huEiHuSoiWnDt@80Y7vuu/Cm4JYNegu46ffDo98D9DPROFbpv9VWzunsKVo1RKZKN/68MhiILKGPQWVj1eNh3Re/X6/UL)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 2902 bytes

Easy to outgolf, but worth giving a shot

```
+>+[<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>>>>[-]++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<<<[-]++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]<[>+<<+>-]<[>+<-]<]>+<<+<<[>>->+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[->+<<[>>>-<<+<-]>[<+>-]>>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]<]>>[-]<<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>.>.>>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]<<[-]<<[>>+<<<+>-]<[>+<-]>>>>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<<[<<<<+>>>>-]+>>[<<<<<<-<+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>[>>>>-<<<<[-]]>>>>>>[-]++<<[<<<<<+>+>>>>-]<<<<<[>>>>>+<<<<<-]>[<<<[-]>[-]>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>[-]]>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<]<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>>>[-]<[>+<<<+>>-]<<[>>+<<-]>>>>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<<[<<<<+>>>>-]+>>[<<<<<<-<+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>[>>>>-<<<<[-]]>>>>>>[-]+++<<[<<<<<+>+>>>>-]<<<<<[>>>>>+<<<<<-]>[<<<[-]>[-]>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>[-]]>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<]<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>>>[-]<<[>>+<<<+>-]<[>+<-]>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]+>[<<<<<-<+>>>>>>-]<<<<<<[>>>>>>+<<<<<<-]>[>>>>-<<<<[-]]>>>>>>+++++<<[<<<<<+>+>>>>-]<<<<<[>>>>>+<<<<<-]>[<<<[-]>[-]>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>[-]]>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<]>++++++<<+<<[>>->+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[->+<<[>>>-<<+<-]>[<+>-]>>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]<]>>[-]<<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>>>[-]<[>+<<<+>>-]<<[>>+<<-]>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]+>[<<<<<-<+>>>>>>-]<<<<<<[>>>>>>+<<<<<<-]>[>>>>-<<<<[-]]>>>>>>++++<<[<<<<<+>+>>>>-]<<<<<[>>>>>+<<<<<-]>[<<<[-]>[-]>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>[-]]>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<]<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>>+>>>+<<<<<<<<<[-]>[-]>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<]>++<<+<<[>>->+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[->+<<[>>>-<<+<-]>[<+>-]>>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]<]>>[-]<<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>>>>-----<<<[-]>>>[<<<+<+>>>>-]<<<<[>>>>+<<<<-]>>>>+++++>+<<<<<<<<<[-]>[-]>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<]>+++<<+<<[>>->+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[->+<<[>>>-<<+<-]>[<+>-]>>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]<]>>[-]<<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>>>>-----<<[-]>>[<<+<<+>>>>-]<<<<[>>>>+<<<<-]>>>>+++++>+<<<<<<<<<[-]>[-]>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<]>++++<<+<<[>>->+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[->+<<[>>>-<<+<-]>[<+>-]>>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]<]>>[-]<<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>+>[-]++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>>+<<<<<<<<<[-]>[-]>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<]>+++++<<+<<[>>->+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[->+<<[>>>-<<+<-]>[<+>-]>>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]<]>>[-]<<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>>>[-]<[>+<<<+>>-]<<[>>+<<-]>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]+>[<<<<<-<+>>>>>>-]<<<<<<[>>>>>>+<<<<<<-]>[>>>>-<<<<[-]]>>>>>>++++++<<<<<<+>>>>[<<<<[-]<+>>>>>-]<<<<<[>>>>>+<<<<<-]>[<<<[-]>[-]>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>[-]]>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<]<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]<<<[-]>[-]>>]<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VbbCsIwDP2gUL8g5EdCH1QQRPBB8PtnLm3XwdxgFzvMYF2z9OTkpKteXuf78/a@ProOCBiZSEZEDJGIEYFInph1KiYjbGKSYQGW5heKoLzSkwzRHKjcQ@Gu5JW9xZmbdaKBWpABaFBQTAnpo6OViYiTYpzkktczdjIkv5FBVcRN0RUKKmcjLZDgBStXd3ktbpwckOZaBLkaRs6ZeHMTrIBAhcHVepPP1lHeFlSyl4Vz@eus7o0zilPfffdnTQ@q5OGlHN@SQy14qEROwAMWX1SoxW0hAuX2/vpsmN6p2wp84E0GFcTa/CO9bdFXCmqpmpQPK@G50PZ4/9XaUYSmKnB@i201aCACLPkrtO/38PdHHUBWKENrbqBDnXt1RpnErvsA)

Comment: This would be shorter if you just generated the characters `0-F` and then hardcoded the printing. How did you manage to make it so long?

Comment: @JoKing possibly, but I just wanted to have fun

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) 6, 40 bytes

```powershell
($l=0..9+'A'..'F')|%{$1=$_;$l|%{"$1$_"}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0Mlx9ZAT89SW91RXU9P3U1ds0a1WsXQViXeWiUHyFRSMVSJV6qt/f8fAA)

Starts at `00` and counts up to `FF`.

Answer (score 2):

### [MUMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS), 57 bytes

```
f i=1:1:48 w $tr(i\16,0),$e("0123456789abcdef",i#16+1),!
```

Output

```
>d ^xmsdgolf
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
a
b
c
d
e
f
10
11
..
28
29
2a
2b
2c
2d
2e
2f
30
```

Explanation

```
f i=1:1:48                     ; loop from 1 to 48
w $tr(i\16,0)                  ; print i div 16, and ditch any zeros
$e("0123456789abcdef",i#16+1)  ; extract the nth character from the string, where n is i mod 16 + 1
!                              ; crlf
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>66</s> 55 Bytes

This should really have been the most obvious approach to me..

```py
a='0123456789ABCDEF'
for x in a:
 for y in a:print x+y
```

**Old (66 Bytes)**: Technically this causes an error after `FF`, but it does reach `30`.

```py
n=1;a='0123456789ABCDEF'
while 1:print a[n/16]*(n>15)+a[n%16];n+=1
```

I assumed string formatting wasn't allowed since I'm pretty sure it would go through base conversion, but if it was allowed, this would be 29 bytes:

```py
n=1
while 1:print"%x"%n;n+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 104 bytes

```
char t[]="0123456789abcdef".toCharArray(),i;void f(){for(;i<99;)System.out.println(""+t[i/16]+t[i++%16]);}
```

If the `i<99` is removed, it still reaches 30, but eventually crashes. I'm not sure if that's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

### J, 47 bytes

```
'0123456789abcdef'{~([:|:2 256$(]#i.),256$i.)16
```

prints 00 to ff

Comment: A much shorter way: `>{;~'0123456789abcdef'`

Comment: Wow, that's very good! But why didn't you post it as an answer, it's only 22 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript <del>74</del> <del>72</del> <del>65</del> 60

```js
//for(i=0,a="0123456789ABCDEF";i++<49;)console.log(a[i>>4]+a[i%16])
for(i=0;i++<48;)console.log((i>>4)+"0123456789ABCDEF"[i%16])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) 1.5: <s>65</s> 59 characters

(56 characters code + 3 characters command line option.)

```
[range(10)]+"a b c d e f"/" "|{a:.[],b:.}|"\(.a)\(.b[])"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -n -r '[range(10)]+"a b c d e f"/" "|{a:.[],b:.}|"\(.a)\(.b[])"' | head
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=[range%2810%29]%2B%22a%20b%20c%20d%20e%20f%22/%22%20%22|%7Ba:.[],b:.%7D|%22%5C%28.a%29%5C%28.b[]%29%22&j=null) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

## jq 1.5: 56 characters

(53 characters code + 3 characters command line option.)

```
[[range(10)]+"a b c d e f"/" "|"\(.[])\(.[])"]|sort[]
```

This produces correct output, however is not exactly a counter: it not generates the values in order, just sorts them after.

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=[[range%2810%29]%2B%22a%20b%20c%20d%20e%20f%22/%22%20%22|%22%5C%28.[]%29%5C%28.[]%29%22]|sort[]&j=null) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Comment: your link for jq doesn't work, and when I fixed it it says there isn't an index file on github :P

Comment: Oops. Thank you @Phase. I was too concentrated on the character count.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 64 bytes

```
h='0123456789abcdef'.split //;h.each{|i|h.each{|j|print i,j,?\s}}
```

Explanation:

```
h = '0123456789abcdef'.split // # Split string of hex chars at
                                # matches of //, returns array
                                # splits array by characters 
h.each { |i|                    # loop 1
  h.each { |j|                  # loop 2
    print i,j,?\s               # print() can take multiple params,
                                # and it is the same as printing
                                # each one using a separate print().
                                # ?x is the same as 'x', so ?\s is
                                # the same as "\s", which is " ".
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 12 bytes

```
       ∘.,⍨16↑⎕D,⎕A
 00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  0A  0B  0C  0D  0E  0F 
 10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  1A  1B  1C  1D  1E  1F 
 20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  2A  2B  2C  2D  2E  2F 
 30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  3A  3B  3C  3D  3E  3F 
 40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  4A  4B  4C  4D  4E  4F 
 50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  5A  5B  5C  5D  5E  5F 
 60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  6A  6B  6C  6D  6E  6F 
 70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  7A  7B  7C  7D  7E  7F 
 80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  8A  8B  8C  8D  8E  8F 
 90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  9A  9B  9C  9D  9E  9F 
 A0  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  AA  AB  AC  AD  AE  AF 
 B0  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9  BA  BB  BC  BD  BE  BF 
 C0  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  CA  CB  CC  CD  CE  CF 
 D0  D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8  D9  DA  DB  DC  DD  DE  DF 
 E0  E1  E2  E3  E4  E5  E6  E7  E8  E9  EA  EB  EC  ED  EE  EF 
 F0  F1  F2  F3  F4  F5  F6  F7  F8  F9  FA  FB  FC  FD  FE  FF
```

Comment: For once, APL matches Pyth.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 34 bytes

The shortest that I can come up with that doesn't use any sort of conversion is:

```perl6
put [X~] (|(0..9),|('A'..'F'))xx 2 # 34 bytes
```

prints `00` ... `FF` space separated in order.
If you want more you can swap `2` for a larger number.
(don't use a number bigger than 4 as it concatenates the values together before outputting anything, so it would use a significant amount of RAM )

---

Shortest that will never stop writing hex values

```perl6
put [R~] (|(0..9),|('A'..'F'))[.polymod: 16 xx*]for 0..* # 56 bytes
```

---

If `printf` were allowed

```perl6
printf "%X ",$_ for 0..* # 24 bytes
```

If a base conversion function were allowed

```perl6
put .base(16)for 0..* # 21 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab: 47 bytes

```
q=[48:57,97:102,''];fliplr(char(combvec(q,q)'))
```

I don't know if it would be considered as counter. The code generates vector of hex numbers from `00` to `ff`. `q` is a string `'0123456789abcdef'` in `double` format. Combvec generates all possible pairs between `q` and `q`. Char converts it to string format and `fliplr` flips the columns to get:

```
00
01
...
08
09
0a
0b
0c
0d
0e
0f
10
11
...
fd
fe
ff
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++14 - 135

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
void f(){std::string a="0123",b="0123456789ABCDEF";for(char c:a)for(char d:b)std::cout<<c<<d<<" ";}
```

Comment: No, it's fine like it is. What compiler are you using? I get `'string' is not a member of 'std'` with mine.

Comment: @Dennis That's a good point. I always forget that it requires including string as it's own. Fixed.

Comment: 1. I'm getting the same error for `cout` as well. I guess you need `iostream` too. 2. It prints the numbers without separation. The challenge requires spaces, tabs or newlines. 3. You should mention the required version of C++.

Answer (score 1):

## GFortran, <s>93</s> 83 bytes

Prints `00` through `ff`. Saved 10 bytes using `print` loops instead of `do.. enddo`.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##Jcs5DoAgEEDR3lPYMZgxivsSe66BCAoFmgn3RxOr/5pvb4qkQnnaHynpS5HS0RCIgctVbqwWTdv1wzjNateHsSx7yIVYIIAEtzheVRL84jmynKHfBH4nur@ZCUdKLw)

```fortran
character(16)H;H='0123456789abcdef'
print*,((H(i:i)//H(j:j),' ',j=1,16),i=1,16)
end
```

Old version: [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##PcZJCoAgFADQfadol0ZhNtgg7b2GOZQuND7e34KgzePZCAlkaE/7JWd1SZAqGUCUYcHFXnW0H8aJzcsqD6WNrQodS7fThjL@zn@7wYVUNwK5zWFCBPKbx4UJWkf@m/MD)

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, <s>44</s> 29 bytes

***-15***, via GammaFunction   [try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/w1aj2kBPz7JWoTpRTy@tVtM6NTkjX0ElLgOI/v8HAA)

```zsh
h=({0..9} {a..f});echo $^h$^h
```

Original (44 bytes): 
`g=0123456789abcdef;h=(${(s::)g});echo $^h$^h`

Comment: Instead of converting to array, you can start there: `h=({0..9} {a..f})`. [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/w1aj2kBPz7JWoTpRTy@tVtM6NTkjX0ElLgOI/v8HAA)

Comment: Thanks! zsh is very golfable :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 42 bytes

Prints hex numbers starting at 0 forever. Will eventually overflow, though.

```
>t>:16;r
Cvn:/61\<
 >$>:10/7*v
^oNndo++0'<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/9@uxM7K0My6iMu5LM9K38wwxoZLwU4FKGagb65VxhWX75eXkq@tbaBu8/8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 84 bytes

```scala
val l=(0 to 9)++"A,B,C,D,E,F".split(",")
l.foreach(x=>l.foreach(y=>println(x+""+y)))
```

Slightly better built version, using what you could call a cartesian product. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcexCsIwEADQ3a84bkrIUVwdUqi2bn5EjBEjRxKao6SI3x5H3/aqd@x6vr@DF7i5mCA0CelRYSrl0zfHwFYdQTKctDE40ZkuNNNCVxxq4SgKCfWBh2deg/Mv1ez4z27HssYknFQziGbXWvdv/wE) Output goes with leading `0`s and a trailing newline. Starts at `00` and counts up to `FF` (`255` in base 10).

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 89 bytes

```scala
for(x<-1 to 48)println(if(x%16>9)x/16+"a,b,c,d,e,f".split(",")(x%16-10)else x/16+""+x%16)
```

First answer, because why not, I like its hacks. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpRCgIhEADQqwxC4LCzlRBLQSx0gA7huiMYorLOh7B0dqP6fbzqbLQ9Ly92Ak8bEnATTmuFRyl793nT7T4akAyXK5YtJIlJB6/bwUzzDdvJTIOytJCjlZi8OtYSg2hFCn9pNGfkWBn@VQ1fxP7uHw) Output goes with leading `0`s and a trailing newline. Starts at `01` and counts up to `30` (`48` in base 10).

Answer (score 1):

## 8088 Assembly, IBM PC DOS, 34 bytes

**Bytes `xxd`:**

```
00000000: 43e8 0900 e806 00b0 20cd 10eb f3b1 04d2  C....... .......
00000010: c38a c324 0f3c 0a7c 0204 0704 30b4 0ecd  ...$.<.|....0...
00000020: 10c3
```

**Unassembled:**

```
        BYTE_LOOP: 
43          INC  BX             ; increment counter  
E8 0009     CALL HB             ; display high byte 
E8 0006     CALL HB             ; display low byte 
B0 20       MOV  AL, ' '        ; display space delimiter
CD 10       INT  10H            ; call BIOS, write char to console 
EB F3       JMP  BYTE_LOOP      ; keep looping forever
        HB PROC 
B1 04       MOV  CL, 4          ; set up bitshift for 4 bits 
D2 C3       ROL  BL, CL         ; shift counter left 4 bits 
8A C3       MOV  AL, BL         ; put counter into AL 
24 0F       AND  AL, 0FH        ; isolate nibble 
3C 0A       CMP  AL, 0AH        ; is nibble A-F? 
7C 02       JL   NOT_ALPHA      ; if not, skip adjustment 
04 07       ADD  AL, 'A'-'9'-1  ; adjust ASCII value to A-F 
        NOT_ALPHA: 
04 30       ADD  AL, '0'        ; decimal to binary convert
B4 0E       MOV  AH, 0EH        ; BIOS tty function
CD 10       INT  10H            ; call BIOS, write char to console 
C3          RET                 ; return to program
        HB ENDP
```

Standalone PC DOS exactable, output is to console and will keep displaying until program is stopped.  Just a scratch ASCII manipulating program here.  There are just no built-ins or convenience methods in x86 or DOS/BIOS APIs to convert binary values to strings for output.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip `-s`](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
_TB16M,h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/PsTJ0MxXJ@P///@6xQA)

### Explanation

```
_TB16M,h
      ,h range 0...99
     M   map using lambda:
_TB16    convert to hexadecimal
         join with spaces(-s flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 35 bytes

```perl
//,map{say$',$_}@,for@,=(0..9,a..f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fXyc3saC6OLFSRV1HJb7WQSctv8hBx1bDQE/PUidRTy9N8///f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Answer (score 1):

## Julia - 58 bytes

```
a="0123456789abcdef"
for i in a
        for j in a
                print(i*j*" ")
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `Ṡ`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kfDṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWtmRCVFMSVCOSU5NiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSZmbGFncz0lRTElQjklQTA=)

##### Explanation

```python
kfDṖ  # Implicit input
kf    # Push "0123456789ABCDEF"
  DṖ  # Cartesian product with itself
      # Join on spaces
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 52 bytes

```
a="0123456789abcdef";main=mapM putStrLn$mapM id[a,a]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 - 57 bytes

```
h='0123456789ABCDEF'
' '.join([i+j for i in h for j in h])
```

This outputs 00 to FF, with spaces between.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 157 bytes

As far as I can tell, this is the only submission so far that can keep counting upwards forever. (Of course, I can't read Haskell or Mumps, but they all *seem* to be doing a two-character loop...) **EDIT:** Okay, not the only one, but perhaps the only one in a non-golfy language?

```py
n=bytearray(b'0')
while 1:
 print(repr(n)[12:-2]);p,o=len(n),1
 while o:
  p-=1;m=n[p];n[p]={57:65,70:48}.get(m,m+1);o=m==70
  if o and p==0:p=1;n[:0]+=b'0'
```

Proof of correctness (wraps the above in a function, changing only `print` to `yield`, and then loops as high as you like):

```py
def golfed_code():
 n=bytearray(b'0')
 while 1:
  yield(repr(n)[12:-2]);p,o=len(n),1
  while o:
   p-=1;m=n[p];n[p]={57:65,70:48}.get(m,m+1);o=m==70
   if o and p==0:p=1;n[:0]+=b'0'

TEST_LIMIT = 100000

for n, h in enumerate(golfed_code()):
 assert hex(n).upper()=='0X'+h,'{} != {}'.format(hex(n).upper(),'0X'+h)
 if n == TEST_LIMIT:
  break
```

(Thanks to Sp3000 for saving me 3 bytes.)

Comment: @Sp3000: Not that I could find (though that doesn't mean one doesn't exist). Everything I tried took more characters, usually because I was constructing a new `bytearray` (and that's a big word). Also: fine, it's the only endless counter *in a non-golfy language*. ;-)

Comment: @Sp3000: I missed that first one (everything *else* I tried with `b''` literals left me with a `bytes`, not a `bytearray`). But the second one means `a` is modified right along with `n`.

Comment: Right, thought they were immutable for some reason. I'm not sure why you're using bytearrays though, surely division/modulo + string building is shorter?

Comment: @Sp3000: Because their string representation automatically ASCIIfies them. I think if I found an approach other than `bytearray`, I'd make it a new answer anyway; it'd be too much like "chuck it out and start over" to edit into this one.

Comment: It's now not the only example of an endless counter from a non-golf language `put [R~] (|(0..9),|('A'..'F'))[.polymod: 16 xx*]for 0..*` in Perl 6